# create simple file used as db on iOS for searching Zip Codes

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have a list of Zip Codes I want to save in my app as some sort of text file that will make it easy to lookup values.  Currently I have this as a PLIST:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
<dict><key>City</key><string>Holtsville</string><key>State</key><string>501</string><key>Zip</key><string>NY</string></dict>
<dict><key>City</key><string>Holtsville</string><key>State</key><string>544</string><key>Zip</key><string>NY</string></dict>
<dict><key>City</key><string>Adjuntas</string><key>State</key><string>601</string><key>Zip</key><string>PR</string></dict>
<dict><key>City</key><string>Aguada</string><key>State</key><string>602</string><key>Zip</key><string>PR</string></dict>
</array>
</plist>
```

Not sure if this is the best way to do this.  There are about 50,00 entries and I want to be able to quickly lookup a value without much overhead.

Comment: SQL is the fastest DB of them all, XML is the slowest.  Use core data, make your life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would store it in an SQLite database. iOS uses SQLite a lot, so it's well supported.
Here's an [excellent tutorial](http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/) on using sqlite in your XCode project.